# Hash Maps with <Key,Value>

Tags: java, hashmap

I write:

```
public interface Map <Key, Value> cells;
```

eclipse complains and says "{ expected".

```
public interface Map <Key, Value> cells{};
```

I then write the above in eclipse and it complains "Syntax error on token "cells", delete this token".

What on earth should i do? Google is not my friend here as i can't find code snippets to work out the syntax of this.

Comment: What is the `interface` keyword doing there? What are trying to achieve?

Comment: if i don't include 'interface' then eclipse complains that Value and Key "cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: That's because `Key` and `Value` are not types. In this case `Key` is a placeholder for the data type that the `Map` object will use for its set of keys. Similarly, `Value` is a placeholder for the data type that it will use for its set of values. A valid combination would be, for example, `Map<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to declare a member variable named `cells`? If so, the way to do it is:

```
public class Foo {

   // ...

   public Map<Type1, Type2> cells;

   // ...

}
```

If you are trying to declare a variable within a method, do this:

```
public class Foo {

    // ...

    public void myMethod() {
        // ...

        Map<Type1, Type2> cells;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Edit:** It looks like you are confused by `Map <Key, Value>`, so I'll try to explain.

`Key` is a placeholder for the data type that the `Map` object will use for its set of keys. Similarly, `Value` is a placeholder for the data type that it will use for its set of values. A valid combination would be, for example, `Map <String, Integer>`. This means that the `Map` object will map a set of `String` objects to a set of `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean

```
public Map<Key, Value> cells;
```

The `interface` keyword is used to *define* an interface. `implements` is used when declaring a `class` that implements a `interface`.

Comment: Dang, It's still not working.
Error:"Key and Value cannot be resolved to a type.".

Comment: That is another error. Key and Value have to be Java classes. A working sample is `public Map<String, Integer> cells;`. I though you just used Key and Value as a placeholder.

Comment: @Randle: look at the comment William Brendel made above. You need to replace "Key" and "Value" with your actual key and value types.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do ? Define a new type or define a member of type Map?

If you are defining a member, you don't need the interface keyword before it.
You only need interface if you are defining a new type.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
public Map<Key,Value> cells;
```

To create a variable called cells of type Map.

```
public interface Map<Key,Value> cells;
```

Is declaring (incorrectly) a user-defined interface called Map - probably not what you are trying to do.